# Dockerfile for building ROS from source

Tags: ros, docker, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to put together a `Dockerfile`that builds ROS Indigo (just `ros_comm` for now) **from source**. I'm more or less following the wiki page instructions: [Installing from source](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source)

I'm running into multiple issues (e.g. running `rosdep update` without sudo) Before I start bombarding you with those (and posting code snippets), I thought I'd ask if someone already knows of a `Dockerfile` that does that. Please keep in mind that the emphasis is on building from source.

Some things I've found so far:

- https://github.com/osblinnikov/ros-docker (trick for running `rosdep update` without `sudo`)
- https://github.com/ruffsl/ubuntu-docker (looks useful, but not sure if it helps me)
- https://github.com/PabloGN/Docker-raspbian-ros-indigo (useful because my end goal is to make this an ARMhf image)

---

Related questions of mine:

- [How to RUN rosdep init and update in Dockerfile](http://answers.ros.org/question/241112/how-to-run-rosdep-init-and-update-in-dockerfile/)
- [What is the purpose of `exec "$@"` in ros_entrypoint.sh ?](http://answers.ros.org/question/241349/what-is-the-purpose-of-exec-in-ros_entrypointsh/)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240536/dockerfile-for-building-ros-from-source/) by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1788 on 2016-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was finally able to put this Dockerfile together: [ubuntu-ros-source](https://github.com/spmaniato/ubuntu-ros-source) It builds and installs ROS Indigo (`ros_comm`) *from source* on top of an Ubuntu Trusty image. The bootstrap tools are installed via `pip`

Adding it as an answer for future reference. Any feedback is highly welcome.

PS. I also ended up writing these as well:

- [resin-ros](https://github.com/spmaniato/resin-ros)
- [resin-raspbian-ros-indigo-qemu](https://github.com/spmaniato/resin-raspbian-ros-indigo-qemu)

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0